# PHP to HTML - preserving indentation

Tags: php, indentation

Having read lines from a js file using php is it possible to preserve indentation when regurgitating it as html - see [glasier.hk](http://glasier.hk) - code tab? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace spaces ' ' to `&nbsp;` or put your code in 'PRE' html tags

```
<pre>
...
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks David pre works fine especially as I also changed pre margin to 0. Maybe I will add some vertical lines like NP++ ... tomorrow! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publixh readable code on the internet, you can do a lot better than jut preserving formating for the same effort - see [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)